# Use front and back (primary and secondary) camera simultaneously on iOS device

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4, iphone-privateapi

I wanted to know if there is any functionality/app on iOS devices which allows you to capture videos simultaneously using front and back cameras showing the outputs in say a split screen. And then later allowing to merge both videos.

Can this functionality be achieved through a user designed app or through a cydia tweak on jailbroken devices ? This question is simply out of curiosity, any relevant information would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, video recording is done using `AVCaptureSession`. So you should try creating two of these, with different input targets each.

---

Edit: As per [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427561/how-can-i-get-autofocus-to-work-in-a-second-avcapturesession-without-recreating/6079123#6079123), it is not possible to create multiple `AVCaptureSession`s.