# The video feed doesn't show when the segmented control is set to video. I'm unable to display the camera feed (preview layer)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, avfoundation

I’m currently building a camera app. It has a segmented control to switch between photo and video. The video stream displays for the photos ViewController but when I switch to the video ViewController the video stream does not display? I’ve been trying everything I can but haven’t figured out why the video stream is not displaying when I toggle the segmented control to video. I put a color on the PreviewLayer to make sure it’s there, I see it on the simulator and it displays on the phone, but the video stream doesn’t display.

If anyone has experience developing camera apps I’d really appreciate the help.

This is code from the project where the preview layer is referenced:

```
class VideoViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var isRecording: Bool = false
    private var permissionGranted = false
    var videoSession = AVCaptureSession()
    
    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    let captureSessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "captureSessionQueue")
    
    let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        previewLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemPink.cgColor

        view.addSubview(startVideoButton)
        view.addSubview(stopVideoButton)
        stopVideoButton.isHidden = true
        
        startVideoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startRecording), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        stopVideoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stopRecording), for: .touchUpInside)

        checkCameraPermissions()
    }

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        previewLayer.frame = view.bounds

        startVideoButton.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 2, y: view.frame.size.height - 80)
        
        stopVideoButton.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 2, y: view.frame.size.height - 80)
    }

private func setUpVideoCamera() {
        guard permissionGranted else { return }
        videoSession.beginConfiguration()
        videoSession.sessionPreset = .high

        let camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)
        let cameraInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput
        do {
            cameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera!)
        } catch {
            print("Error setting device video input: \(error)")
            return
        }

        if videoSession.canAddInput(cameraInput) {
            videoSession.addInput(cameraInput)
        }

        if videoSession.canAddOutput(movieOutput) {
            videoSession.addOutput(movieOutput)
        }
        
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        previewLayer.session = videoSession
        videoSession.startRunning()
        
        // Add audio device
        
        do {
            let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)
            let audioDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice!)

            if videoSession.canAddInput(audioDeviceInput) {
                videoSession.addInput(audioDeviceInput)
            } else {
                print("Could not add audio device input to the session")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Could not create audio device input: \(error)")
        }
        
    }
```

Here are screenshots of my app being used:

[image: screenshots from the simulator]

[image: screenshots from the simulator]

Comment: I think you have better used only one `AVCaptureSession`, and just `session.removeInput` when switching. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/6079123/17771995

Comment: Ok @Elevo Thanks. I have three view controllers, the ViewController.swift file, the PhotoViewController.swift file and the VideoViewController file. The segmented control is defined in the ViewController file, are you suggesting I define the AVCaptureSession there? Also how do use the session.removeInput.

Comment: you could make a custom Delegate Protocol, achieved in your `ViewController ` and that the return value can be got in `PhotoViewController ` or `VideoViewController `. Take TableViewDelegate as an example. `rows: Int { delegate.tableView(_:numberOfRows:) }` in your subViewController