# How to check the auto focus is still going on in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice, avcapture

I created camera app now what i want to do is need to check is the focus going on continuously or stopped.

**This is what i tried :**

```
 NSError *error=nil;
    //Capture Session
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc]init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;

    //Add device
    AVCaptureDevice *device =
    [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    // SETUP FOCUS MODE
    if ([device lockForConfiguration:nil]) {

        [device setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus];

        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"error while configuring focusMode");
    }
    NSLog(@"%@" ,NSStringFromCGPoint(device.focusPointOfInterest));
    if ([device isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus] && [device lockForConfiguration:&error]){
        [device setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus];
        if ([device isFocusPointOfInterestSupported])
            [device setFocusPointOfInterest:CGPointMake(0.5f,0.5f)];
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"problem ");
    }

    //Input
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:nil];

    if (!input)
    {
        NSLog(@"No Input");
    }

    [session addInput:input];

    //Preview Layer
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
    UIView *myView = viewForCamera;
    previewLayer.frame = myView.bounds;
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    [viewForCamera.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];

    //Start capture session
    [session startRunning];
```

I searched is there any delegate method but i didn't get ,Please help me to solve this problem .

Comment: please mention the down vote reason so that i will update my question

Comment: Above your code crash?

Comment: @user3182143 thanks bro still i am facing this problem

Comment: @user3182143 no bro

Comment: I tried your above code.It crashes.

Comment: It says 'Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** Can't add a nil AVCaptureInput''

Comment: @user3182143 bro look at this http://paste.ofcode.org/hkM9CmLtP9XkktMXrYW6PZ

Comment: @user3182143 bro got it ?

Comment: Do you run with device or simulator?

Comment: @user3182143 device bro 5s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120599/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-user3182143).

Comment: Are you there brother?

Comment: @user3182143 yes bro tell me ?

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Comment: @user3182143 no bro i didn't get any solution

Comment: Please come to discussion part.I posted the code there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution.I tried with sample.I googled and went through lot of answers.

> We must set the point of interest before calling setFocusMode

In your coding you have not called the point of interest

```
if ([device isFocusPointOfInterestSupported])
{
   [device setFocusPointOfInterest:CGPointMake(0.5f,0.5f)];
   [device setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus];
             //OR
   [device setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus];
   [device unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

[AutoFocus is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391203/focus-autofocus-not-working-in-camera-avfoundation-avcapturesession)

Then finding whether the Auto focus is going or not

[Auto Focus Observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100357/iphone-camera-autofocus-observer)

Comment: Where is it this group?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81492/tamil-android-and-ios-developers @user3182143

Comment: Not a issue.I will come.Now not a time.I will join.

Comment: Defnitely I will join.